# Printing a decimal in non-scientific form in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, decimal, precision, mathematica-7

I would like to print the number represented by `3*10^-9` in non-scientific form: `0.000000003`.  How can I do this?  `NumberForm[N[3*10^-9], {Infinity, 10}]` does not work.  Thank you.

Comment: What's your reason for needing to do this?

Comment: I need to print these numbers in this form for a text file.

Comment: Ah ok I see, well the answer below should work then.

Comment: There are some useful related answers on the new [Mathematica-specific StackExchange site](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=NumberForm+AccountingForm&submit=search)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
AccountingForm[3. 10^-9, NumberSigns -> {"-", ""}]
AccountingForm[-3. 10^-9, NumberSigns -> {"-", ""}]

(* 0.000000003 *)
(* -0.000000003 *)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work so well for me because AccountingForm converts negative signs to parentheses, like an accountant would.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the following way is how you're "supposed" to do it.

```
NumberForm[N[3*10^-9], ExponentFunction -> (Null &)]
```

The ExponentFunction option set like this just specifies that you don't want any exponents. (You can also use that option to restrict output to exponents of certain powers.)

(I'm using Mathematica 7.0 .)